# How to integrate Google Closure Compiler as a build step in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, google-closure-compiler

Is there any reference or tutorial for this? And if it's possible, have the javascript file being built only if the file is modified.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might be able to try this:

http://closurecompiler.codeplex.com/documentation,

But I couldn't get it to work and ended up writing a batch file and hooked it up as a post-build process in the project properties.  I've been pretty happy with that solution as it allows me to easily (and in a more standardized fashion) tweak the closure parameters.  And any errors from it get reported to you whenever you build.

Comment: We do the same. Using the batch file approach is simple and configurable. It is an extra step, but if you http://www.launchy.net, it's just a few milliseconds away.